# Type mismatch of "root reducer"

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

In my Redux store, I am initializing a `persistedReducer` which takes the redux-persist config and "rootReducer":

`client/src/redux/store.ts`:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import autoMergeLevel2 from 'redux-persist/es/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2';
import rootReducer from './rootReducer'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

The rootReducer itself is being declared and exported like so:

`client/src/redux/rootReducer.ts`:

```
import { combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { IUserState } from "../interfaces/user";
import userSlice from "./features/userSlice";

export interface RootState {
  user: IUserState;
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userSlice.reducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

The `userSlice` reducer we are importing and adding to the rootReducer looks like this:

`client/src/redux/features/userSlice.ts`:

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { IUserState } from "../../interfaces/user";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import userApi from "../../apis/user";
import { RootState } from "../store";

const initialState: IUserState = {
  _id: "",
  ipAddress: "",
  createdAt: "",
  alignment: "",
  loading: false,
  error: "",
};

export const getUser = createAsyncThunk("user/getUser", async (_, thunkApi) => {
  try {
    const response = await userApi.getUser();
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    throw thunkApi.rejectWithValue({ error: "user not initialized" });
  }
});

export const updateUser = createAsyncThunk<IUserState, any, { state: RootState }>(
  "user/updateUser",
  async (data: any, thunkApi) => {
    console.log("document", data);
    try {
      const user = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.user);
      const response = await userApi.updateUser(user, data);
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      throw thunkApi.rejectWithValue({ error: "user not updated" });
    }
  }
);

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "userData",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    getUser: (state, action: PayloadAction<IUserState>) => {
      state = Object.assign(state, action.payload);

      return state;
    },
    updateUser: (state, action: PayloadAction<IUserState>) => {
      state = Object.assign(state, action.payload);

      return state;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(getUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state = Object.assign(state, action.payload);
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = "";
    });
    builder.addCase(getUser.pending, (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = "";
    });
    builder.addCase(getUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.error.message || "user not initialized";
    });
  },
});

export const { getUser: getUserAction, updateUser: updateUserAction } =
  userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice;
```

The user state interface is imported from `client/src/interfaces/user.ts`, and looks like this:

```
export type IUserState = {
  _id: string
  ipAddress: string
  createdAt: string
  alignment: string
  loading: boolean
  error: string
}
```

The error I'm encountering in my client output states:

```
Argument of type 'Reducer<{ user: IUserState; }, UnknownAction, Partial<{ user: IUserState | undefined; }>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<unknown, UnknownAction, unknown>'.
  Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ user: IUserState; } | Partial<{ user: IUserState | undefined; }> | undefined'
```

There is a separate error from the Typescript compiler in my `updateUser` asyncThunk which says `Property 'user' does not exist on type 'PersistPartial'`.  I am not certain if this is related to the terminal error that's complaining about a type mismatch with the Reducer. Casting `rootReducer` as `any` obviously makes the error go away, but I'd like to avoid that, if possible. It seems like this may be an issue with the way I am defining the RootState interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is in your `updateUser` Thunk, at least a couple issues.

1. There's no need really to parameterize `createAsyncThunk` as it should already infer the correct types based on the store and the payload creator argument.
2. `updateUser` isn't a React component or custom React hook, so it ***can't*** use the `useSelector` hook. Use `thunkApi.getState` to access the current state value.
3. `rejectWithValue` should be returned, not thrown, from the Thunk.

```js
export const updateUser = createAsyncThunk<
  IUserState,
  any,
  {
    state: RootState,
    rejectValue: {
      error: string;
    }
  }
>("user/updateUser", (data: any, thunkApi) => {
  try {
    const user = thunkApi.getState().user;
    return userApi.updateUser(user, data);
  } catch (error) {
    return thunkApi.rejectWithValue({ error: "user not updated" });
  }
});
```

or

```js
export const updateUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "user/updateUser",
  (data: any, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      const user = (thunkApi.getState() as RootState).user;
      return userApi.updateUser(user, data);
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue({ error: "user not updated" });
    }
  }
);
```

Additionally you have issues in the `userSlice` with the state updates. You should only ever *mutate* the state ***or*** *return* an entirely new state reference value, and you should ***never*** reassign the state. `state = Object.assign(state, payload)` may technically works since the reference is the same, but you should not make it a habit of doing `state = ...` in your RTK reducers.

```js
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "userData",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    getUser: (state, action: PayloadAction<IUserState>) => {
      // Just mutate state
      Object.assign(state, action.payload);

      // or return new state value
      // return action.payload;
    },
    updateUser: (state, action: PayloadAction<IUserState>) => {
      // Just mutate state
      Object.assign(state, action.payload);

      // or return new state value
      // return action.payload;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(getUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      Object.assign(state, action.payload);
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = "";
    });
    builder.addCase(getUser.pending, (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = "";
    });
    builder.addCase(getUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload || "user not initialized";
    });
  },
});
```